# What is the rotation matrix around an arbitrary independent vector?

Tags: matrices, vectors, rotations

Suppose I have an arbitrary independent vector `B` that is $[0, 0, 1]^T$ and a position vector `P` $[P_x, P_y, P_z]$. I want to create a rotation matrix from this. Some sources say to get a rotation matrix you have to $W = P ÷ ||P||$ from this you get $ V = (W*B) ÷ ||(W*B)|| $, and $ U = W*V $ so the rotation matrix is $$R = \begin{bmatrix}
    U_x & V_x & W_x \\ 
    U_y & V_y & W_y \\ 
    U_z & V_z & W_z \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this the correct rotation matrix and I don't know how to compute `B`. Can you explain it to me in detail.

Tanks!

Comment: Questions should be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: If a  set containis just  one vector and that  vector is non-zero, then the set is linearly indepent, so the meaning of "Suppose I ...independent vector" is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify what is given and what is to found.  You first sentence says that $B$ is given, then your question asks how to find $B$.  If you are trying to find a rotation martix, it would be helpful to think about what stays fixed and what moves during the rotation.  Providing a concrete example with real numbers is also helpful.  Finally, I assume that by $*$ you intended the cross product $\times$.  What your math seems to be doing is forming three perpendicular vectors.  These can be used to form an orthogonal matrix., it however appears that it is left handed (det = -1), not a valid $R$